# Create separate pandas dataframes based on a column and operate on them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have the following code, which works, but surely there has to be a more efficient way to loop through these steps.

First, here's the data frame. You will see we have some tweets about some cereals, nothing fancy.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Cheerios', 'I love Cheerios they are the best'], ['FrostedFlakes', 'Frosted Flakes taste delicious'], ['FruityPebbles', 'Fruity Pebbles is a terrible cereal'], ['Cheerios', 'Honey Nut Cheerios are the greatest cereal'], ['FrostedFlakes', 'Frosted Flakes are grrrreat'], ['FruityPebbles', 'Fruity Pebbles are terrible']], columns=['Label', 'Tweet'])
```

Now, I create separate data frames for each value of the column "Label," i.e. a data frame for each cereal

```
cereals0 = df[df["Label"] == 'Cheerios']
cereals1 = df[df["Label"] == 'FrostedFlakes']
cereals2 = df[df["Label"] == 'FruityPebbles']
```

Now I split the text in the "Tweet" column for each data frame, then count those words, then sort the data frames by that count

```
cereals0 = cereals0.Tweet.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().reset_index()
cereals1 = cereals1.Tweet.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().reset_index()
cereals2 = cereals2.Tweet.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().reset_index()
```

Finally I add labels to the columns

```
cereals0.columns = ['Word', 'Frequency']
cereals1.columns = ['Word', 'Frequency'] 
cereals2.columns = ['Word', 'Frequency']
```

Is there a way to do these three steps in a FOR loop so I can avoid copying and pasting?

I have tried something like

```
for cereal in df.Label.unique():
    cereal = df[df["Label"] == cereal].Tweet.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().reset_index()
    
    cereal.columns = ['Word', 'Frequency']
```

But this gets me nothing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your examples you probably want to look at `.pivot_table` or [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab):

```py
df = df.assign(Tweet=df["Tweet"].str.split()).explode("Tweet")
print(pd.crosstab(df["Tweet"], df["Label"]))
```

Prints:

```
Label      Cheerios  FrostedFlakes  FruityPebbles
Tweet                                            
Cheerios          2              0              0
Flakes            0              2              0
Frosted           0              2              0
Fruity            0              0              2
Honey             1              0              0
I                 1              0              0
Nut               1              0              0
Pebbles           0              0              2
a                 0              0              1
are               2              1              1
best              1              0              0
cereal            1              0              1
delicious         0              1              0
greatest          1              0              0
grrrreat          0              1              0
is                0              0              1
love              1              0              0
taste             0              1              0
terrible          0              0              2
the               2              0              0
they              1              0              0
```